# Travel from Cameron Highlands to Gua Musang

Tags: public-transport, malaysia

I'm planning a trip, and my goal is to travel from the [Cameron Highlands](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Cameron_Highlands) to [Gua Musang](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Gua_Musang) and eventually take the [jungle railway](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Jungle_Railway) from Gua Musang.

Unfortunately, I won't have access to a car for this journey. Despite my efforts, my research, including checking [websites](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Malaysia#By_bus_2) like busonlineticket.com, has not yielded viable options. Additionally, other threads on TripAdvisor seem to be quite dated.

Can anyone provide up-to-date information or recommendations on how to make this journey via public transportation or any alternative means? Or even suggest an interesting alternative route.

Your insights and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having visited both (but not on the same trip), Gua Musang is *very* deep in the jungle and the road from there to the Cameron Highlands looks very small and thinly trafficked.  I would be quite astonished if there was any public transport between the two.

Your realistic choices are to hire a taxi to take you, hitchhike a ride with locals (you may be in for long wait), or backtrack via Ipoh and/or KL.

Comment: Yeah Ipoh sounds like the most probable choice...